# UserManager not updating custom Identity User properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, .net-core

I'm using Using aspnet Identity + OpenIddict to do authentication on top of EF Core.

I extended the `IdentityUser` class to include two lists; `StudyTags` and `ExpertTags`, along with a few other properties:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        StudyTags = new List<Tag>();
        ExpertTags = new List<Tag>();
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> StudyTags { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> ExpertTags { get; set; }
}
```

This is all well and good, however, when I want to update these lists and save them, the update only seems to persist in a certain scope. For instance, if I call the below API call twice, the first time adds the tag to the proper list, and the second time logs a message saying it's already been added. I can inspect the user and verify that the tag is in the list as expected.

```
    [Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [HttpPost("add/tag/{tagType}/{tagName}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddTagToUser(int tagType, string tagName) 
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User) as ApplicationUser;
        if(user == null) 
        {
            _logger.LogError("User not found");
            return BadRequest();
        }

        TagType type = (TagType)tagType;

        var tag = _tagService.GetTagByName(tagName);
        if(tag == null)
        {
            _logger.LogError("No tag corresponding to tagName '{0}'", tagName);
            return BadRequest();
        }

        if(type == TagType.Study)
        {
            if(user.StudyTags.Contains(tag))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("{0} already assigned to {1}", tag.ToString(), user.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("{0} added to {1}", tag.ToString(), user.ToString());
                user.StudyTags.Add(tag);
            }
        }
        else if(type == TagType.Expert)
        {
            if(user.ExpertTags.Contains(tag))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("{0} already assigned to {1}", tag.ToString(), user.ToString());
            }
            else 
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("{0} added to {1}", tag.ToString(), user.ToString());
                user.ExpertTags.Add(tag);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogError("No tagType corresponding to {0}", tagType);
            return BadRequest();
        }


        var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

        if(result.Succeeded)
        {
            return Ok(result);
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogError("Updating Tag failed");
            return BadRequest();
        } 
    }
```

However, if I just try to do a `Get` of the same user, the StudyTags and ExpertTags lists are empty.

```
    [Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if(user == null)
        {
            _logger.LogError("User not found");
            return BadRequest();
        }

        return Ok(user); 
    }
```

Am I doing something incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your properties should be marked as virtual. If the records exist in your database but just aren't being fetched when you run the GET method and fetch data for the user, then it's because of lazy loading. The virtual keyword will allow them to be populated when you access the user object.

This is what you want:

```
public virtual List<Tag> StudyTags { get; set; }
public virtual List<Tag> ExpertTags { get; set; }
```

UPDATE:

So it looks like what's required is a M:M relationship. Since EF Core doesn't support the auto-creation of the junction class, it'll have to be made explicitly. So in the end, your models must look like:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser 
{
    //Other Properties
    public ICollection<Tag> StudyTags { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> ExpertTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    //Other Properties
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserTags 
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

And your context needs to be updated to include:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserTag>()
        .HasKey(x => new { x.User, x.TagId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserTag>()
        .HasOne(x => x.User)
        .WithMany(y => y.UserTags)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserTag>()
        .HasOne(x => x.Tag)
        .WithMany(y => y.UserTags)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.TagId);
}
```

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't solve the problem. You're right that they probably should be marked virtual anyway.

Comment: What does your Tag class look like?

Comment: Just strings for Id, Name, and Description. Very simple.

Comment: By the looks of it, you want a many to many relationship. One user can have many tags and one tag can belong to many users, right? If so, your Tag class will have to be updated to include a virtual property to reference a collection of user objects as well (i.e. public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; })

Comment: Yes, ultimately, that's what I want. However, would that have any impact on what is occurring?

Comment: What you require is a mapping/junction/intersect table between Tag and ApplicationUser (AspnetUsers) tables. This will get created only if both the objects hold collection references to one another - this is how EF operates. Right now, the Tag object holds no reference to the ApplicationUser so the desired mapping can't occur between them.

Comment: Also, you should ideally use HashSet<Tag> in your ApplicationUser constructor than List<Tag>. The HashSet will be faster than a List, if you're willing on sacrificing order. And the same for your objects, use ICollection<> instead of List<> so you're not unnecessarily loading stuff unless you need it.

Comment: An, okay. I'll make the updates you suggest and see what happens.

Comment: I'm using EFCore, so I have to put in a [join table for a many-to-many relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many).

Comment: No - I don't want a many-to-many relationship yet. I should not have to do this in order to properly populate a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: You don't have a one to many relationship either. If you want a 1:M relationship, then you have to include a virtual property for ApplicationUser in your Tag class (i.e. public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }). Having this in your Tag class will enforce the 1:M that you're trying to achieve.

Comment: oh, you're right. I totally don't want that. However, I also do not care which tags are assigned to which users. I really only care about what tags a user has.

Comment: The purpose of EF when using Code First is to help build out your data model. You can't just add a property and expect that it'll figure everything out on its own - it has to make sense from a relational point of view. What you need is a M:M. You're trying to do is analogous to making a coin with only one side... it's not possible. The only way you'll know correctly which tags a user has is if you know which tags are assigned to which users.

Comment: Ah ha, I see! Okay - I'll try and wrap my head around doing the M:M properly. Thank you.

Comment: I've updated the answer. If this helped you out and solved your issue, mark the question as answered.

Comment: Shouldn't all `ICollections` be of type `<UserTag>`? And then there should be mappings: `.WithMany(y => y.StudyTags)` & `.WithMany(y => y.ExpertTags)`

If so, I'm not certain how to update these collections in my code, since now I'm dealing with `UserTag` instead of `User` and `Tag`.

Comment: Oh, I probably just have to do a `user.StudyTags.Select(ut => ut.Tag);` in order to get the tags, yeah?

Comment: I've made the updates, but am receiving the build error: `The navigation property 'User' cannot be added to the entity type 'UserTag' because a property with this same name already exists on entity type 'UserTag'`.

Comment: I ended up getting this system running with two separate join tables. However, my `studyTags` and `expertTags` are still not being populated in the `Get` request.

Comment: Make your properties virtual (ICollections, Tag, and Application - all of them). And if you've turned off lazy loading as suggested in the other answer, remove that change... lazy loading must be enabled.

Comment: Lazy loading is not implemented in EF7/Core. The `virtual` tag effectively does nothing in this context.

Comment: Ok, then in that case, instead of using the UserManager, you can use your context (provided it inherits from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`) as follows: `var user = db.Users.Where(x => x.Id == "YourUserIdHash").Include(x => x.StudyTags).Include(x => x.StudyTags).FirstOrDefault();`, where `db` is an instance of your context object.

Answer (score 0):

In your `_userManager.GetUserAsync` method you have to write the code to eagerly load the StudyTags like below:

```
context.User.Include(x => x.StudyTags).Include(x => x.ExpertTags);
```

If your property is virtual, then it will only be loaded when you access the property (lazy loading). If your property is not virtual, then it should be loaded when object holding the property is loaded.

If you want to turn off lazy loading globally you can include this in your context constructor:

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; // careful though keep reading
```

The above switch has a global effect so if not careful it can cause performance issues since the whole object graph will be loaded every time, even though you may not need it.

To turn off lazy loading for a single property, make it NON virtual.

Comment: The properties were non-virtual to begin with.

Comment: That is a good point. Sorry I overlooked it. How about using the Include method as I have shown above, does that work?

Comment: I'm not sure where `context` would be in scope - I'm only injecting `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` in order to stay decoupled from my DB Context.

Comment: I'm not using a custom `UserManager` or `UserStore`, perhaps I need to.

Comment: In your get method simply access the property to force it to load like this: var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User); var studyTags = user.StudyTags. Do the same for your other property. Now your user will have the property loaded.